# Why am I getting std::out_of_range error?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to make a function that reorders the elements of a vector if it is not in ascending order. I wrote this but when I compile it I get:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' what(): vector::_M_range_check

Could someone tell me what is wrong with my function? Thanks.

```
void reorder(vector<double>& orderA)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < orderAngle.size(); ++i)
    {
        temp = orderA.at(i);
        orderA.at(i) = orderA.at(i+1);
        orderA.at(i+1) = temp;
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: i + 1 is out of range when i = orderAngle.size() - 1. On top of that, code doesn't do what it should. You need full blown sorting function.

Comment: When your counter  equals `size -1`, it's going to try to get the last element and the next one, which doesn't exist. Your loop function should be `i < orderAngle.size() -1`

Comment: Always write `return` at the end of your functions. If you forget to write it, the function will execute forever.

Comment: Wouldn't `auto temp = orderA.at(0); orderA.erase(orderA.begin()); orderA.push_back(temp);` be likely to be more efficient?

Comment: @OlegAndriyanov: the `return` statement is not required for functions that have a `void` return type.

Comment: Nor will the function repeat forever should a required return be left out. It could repeat forever, but it could also mangle the stack, outright crash, or eat your neighbour's cat. It might even behave as you expect sometimes and not others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- As mentioned in the comments by Olzhas, your code will go out of range when i becomes equal to orderAngle.size(), so you need to change your for loop to:

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < orderAngle.size() - 1; ++i)
```

2- Your algorithm doesn't achieve what you want to achieve.

3- Do you really need to write your own algorithm to sort a vector of doubles?
How about using something like the following code:

```
sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](double x, double y) {

   return (x < y);
});
```